# Count how many values have duplicates in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have values in a column like:

```
08FHI800
08FHI800
08FHI800
07FJM933
07FJM933
89MNA900
```

I need a formula that tells me how many items in the column have corresponding duplicates.  In this case, it would be 2.

Comment: OK - what have you tried?

Comment: Pivot Tables, which gets the trick done, but I wanted a formula that will just tell me the number of ones with duplicates instead of counting all the rows in the pivot table that have >1 for the Count Column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula assuming data in A2:A100

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A100<>"")/COUNTIF(A2:A100,A2:A100&"")-(COUNTIF(A2:A100,A2:A100&"")=1))`

It will ignore blanks

Comment: Amazing -- `SUMPRODUCT` keeps surprising me.

Comment: I don't even know how this works, but I'm impressed.  Could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A12<>"")/COUNTIF(A1:A12,A1:A12&"")-(COUNTIF(A1:A12,A1:A12&"")=1))
```

Using this data as an example

```
Row#  ColA

1      1

2      2

3      2

4      2

5      3

6      4

7      5

8      5

9      6

10     6

11     6

12     7
```

Break the function apart into 3 components:

```
(A1:A12<>””)

COUNTIF(A1:A12,A1:A12&””)

COUNTIF(A1:A12,A1:A12&””)=1
```

Component 1

```
(A1:A12<>””) evaluates to an array containing {T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T} ---------(1)
```

Component 2

```
COUNTIF(A1:A12,A1:A12&””)
```

evaluates to

```
COUNTIF({1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,6,7},{1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6,6,7}
```

and it counts the number of times each value appears in the range
This in turn evaluates to:

```
{1,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,1}    -----------------(2)
```

(the &”” is to avoid #DIV/0 error)

Now, because of the brackets we need to evaluate (Component 1 / Component 2) first before looking at Component 3.

Component 1/Component 2 is

```
(A1:A12<>"")/COUNTIF(A1:A12,A1:A12&"")
```

So from (1) and (2),

```
{T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T}/{1,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,1}
```

which evaluates to:

```
{1,0.3333,0.3333,0.3333,1,1,0.5,0.5,0.333,0.333,0.333,1}
```

Now we can look at 
Component 3

```
COUNTIF(A1:A12,A1:A12&””)=1
```

We already have the first bit of this:

```
COUNTIF(A1:A12,A1:A12&””)
```

from (2), which evaluates to

```
{1,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,1}
```

Combining this with =1 becomes

```
COUNTIF(A1:A12,A1:A12&””)=1
```

Which in turn evaluates to

```
{T,F,F,F,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,T}
```

So, finally combining this all together, we have

```
SUMPRODUCT({1,0.3333,0.3333,0.3333,1,1,0.5,0.5,0.333,0.333,0.333,1} - {T,F,F,F,T,T,F,F,F,F,F,T})
```

Now, T equates to 1 and F equates to 0 so this now becomes:

```
SUMPRODUCT({1-1,0.333-0, 0.333-0, 0.333-0,1-1,1-1,0.5-0,0.5-0, 0.333-0, 0.333-0, 0.333-0,1-1}
```

Becomes

```
SUMPRODUCT({0,0.333,0.333,0.333,0,0,0.5,0.5,0.333,0.333,0.333,0}
```

As there is only one array, SUMPRODUCT simply sums the elements

```
1+1+1 =3
```

There are 3 items which are duplicated.